# SQL to move rows up or down in two-table arrangement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables that I designed this way with a possible reshuffling of elements in mind:

```
1. [dbo.test_db_002] with columns:
[id] = INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
[name] = NVARCHAR(255)
```

and

```
2. [dbo.test_db_003] with columns:
[ord] = INT
[itmid] = INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
```

[itmid] column has a constraint linking it to [dbo.test_db_002].[id] like so:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo.test_db_003] 
ADD CONSTRAINT fk1 FOREIGN KEY ([itmid]) 
REFERENCES [dbo.test_db_002]([id]) 
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Say, [dbo.test_db_002] table has the following data:

```
[id] [name] 
3    John
5    Mary
8    Michael
10   Steve
13   Jack
20   Pete
```

and [dbo.test_db_003] has the following ordering data:

```
[ord] [itmid]
1      5
4      8
5      13
8      3
10     10
13     20
```

So when I retrieve names from the database I use the following SQL:

```
SELECT [name]
FROM   [dbo.test_db_002] t1
LEFT JOIN [dbo.test_db_003] t2 ON t1.[id]=t2.[itmid]
ORDER BY t2.[ord] ASC
```

It produces the list of names (ordered by the [dbo.test_db_003].[ord] column):

```
Mary
Michael
Jack
John
Steve
Pete
```

What I am looking for is an option to move each of the names up and down the list. For instance, if I want to move "John" one position up, what do I do?

So far I came up with this partial SQL:

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT [id], [ord], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t2.[ord] ASC) AS rowNum
    FROM [dbo.test_db_002] t1
    LEFT JOIN [dbo.test_db_003] t2 ON t1.[id] = t2.[itmid]
)
```

That will select the following:

```
rowNum  [id]  [ord]
1        1     5
2        4     8
3        5     13
4        8     3
5        10    10
6        13    20
```

So I understand that I need to shift values in [ord] column up by one starting from the index 3 (since "John" index is 4) and then somehow make "John"'s [ord] to be set to 5, but how do you do that?

Comment: What will be the process by which a name is moved up or down the list? Does the ordering table get updated, or will some other action trigger the change?

Comment: Yes, I need to come up with the UPDATE statement to update the ordering table, i.e. [dbo.test_db_003].[ord] column. Also the move up or down can be only a single step - in other words, one cannot move 2 or more positions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prepared a [complete demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/2072/demo-ahmd0-rows-switch) for you how this can work on data.stackexchange.com.
The solution is tailored to your comment:

> the move up or down can be only a single step - in other words, one
> cannot move 2 or more positions

In the example I make John trade ordinal positions with Jack above him:

```
WITH x AS (
  SELECT t2.itmid, t2.ord
  FROM   dbo.test_db_002 t1
  LEFT   JOIN dbo.test_db_003 t2 ON (t1.id = t2.itmid)
  WHERE  t1.name = 'John'  -- must be unique, or query by id ...
  )
  , y AS (
  SELECT TOP 1
         t.itmid, t.ord
  FROM   dbo.test_db_003 t, x
  WHERE  t.ord < x.ord     -- smaller ord = "above"
  ORDER  BY t.ord DESC
  )
UPDATE dbo.test_db_003 SET ord = z.ord
FROM (
   SELECT x.itmid, y.ord FROM x,y
   UNION ALL
   SELECT y.itmid, x.ord FROM x,y
   ) z
WHERE  dbo.test_db_003.itmid = z.itmid
```

###Major points:

0. Use two CTE to structure the query:
1. Get John's id & ordinal position
2. Get the same for the person above him
3. Prepare two rows where these two switch ordinal numbers with the help of `UNION ALL`
4. Use these two rows in a now simple `UPDATE`

- The ordinal position `ord` must allow passing duplicates for this to work.
- If there is nobody 'above', the query will silently do nothing.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! Let me study it and I'll mark it as an answer. You are awesome! I appreciate your time.